# Multiplying range by percentage of days left in current month

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble with the very last part of this code I've been writing.

I am trying to have excel calculate the percentage of days left in the current month based on today. Then it multiplies a range of cells by that value.

When It actually multiplies, all the cells change to "#NAME". I checked with msgbox's and the calculation part of it is going correctly (It's finding the correct percentage) but when plugged in to the last formula to multiply, it doesn't work.

When I take out the variable from the formula and put in the actual number, it works fine. I assume there is something wrong with how I'm writing the variable into the final sequence. What am I doing wrong with my formatting?

```
Sub MultiplyDayRatio()

Dim rngData As Range
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim DaysLeft As Integer
Dim DaysInMonth As Integer
Dim PercentLeft As Double


MyDate = Date

'DaysInMonth = EoMonth(Today(), 0)

DaysLeft = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0) - Date

'MsgBox DaysLeft

DaysInMonth = (MonthDays(Month(MyDate)))

'MsgBox DaysInMonth

PercentLeft = DaysLeft / DaysInMonth

'MsgBox PercentLeft

Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary").Range("G3:G70")
rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*PercentLeft.value")


End Sub
```

Comment: `PercentLeft` is a `Double` - it doesn't have a `.value`.

Comment: Also, @BigBen PercentLeft is a variable, shouldn't go between ". Right? Didn't answer that because I've never use Evaluate.. So I gave him a simple loop.

Comment: @Damian - yes it should also not be within quotes.

Comment: Yeah, I had also tried putting it outside of quotes, but then it errored out. Without the .value, it caused the same kind of problem too. But thank you Damian, your fix to my problem works just fine for what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried with `Evaluate(range(rngData.Address) * PercentLeft)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LPerry. Try this:

```
Sub MultiplyDayRatio()

    Dim rngData As Range, C As Range '<-- new variable
    Dim MyDate As Date
    Dim DaysLeft As Integer
    Dim DaysInMonth As Integer
    Dim PercentLeft As Double


    MyDate = Date

    'DaysInMonth = EoMonth(Today(), 0)

    DaysLeft = WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0) - Date

    'MsgBox DaysLeft

    DaysInMonth = (MonthDays(Month(MyDate)))

    'MsgBox DaysInMonth

    PercentLeft = DaysLeft / DaysInMonth

    'MsgBox PercentLeft

    Set rngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary").Range("G3:G70")
    'rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*PercentLeft.value") 'instead this

    'Try this
    For Each C In rngData
        C = C * PercentLeft
    Next C

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't think about going through cells individually. That probably makes more sense. I'll mark this as the answer once the 15 minutes of post life is up.

Comment: @LPerry or you can fix your evaluate to `rngData = Evaluate(rngData.Address & "*" & PercentLeft)`

Comment: What BigBen says is also good. I don't really know that function but I shall explore it!

Comment: While looping works, it's incredibly slow on larger sheets. You should really opt for applying the calculation to the whole range in one go via BigBen's route

Comment: when you loop cells using for each it's not that slow